# Shiny: Get exact datapath from fileInput instead of temporary datapath

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I'm building an app for which I need to select files from local system and fetch the exact path of the selected file. How can I use fileInput to get the exact path. As it provides below details:
name | size | type | datapath
But it is a temporary path which is not exact.

Is there some way to get the path of file selected.

Comment: For security reasons, a browser will not give you access to the full path for a local file. And since shiny is a server, it does not assume it can interact with the clients local files so it needs to upload a copy so it can interact with the data. What exactly are you trying to accomplish that you need the "exact" data path and not just the data in the file?

Comment: @MrFlick I'm passing the path to some function at later point so need to have the exact path. I have also tried using **shinyFileChoose** but using this I'm unable to browse files from local system.

Comment: It you need access to a local/client file system then a shiny web application may not be the right choice for you.

Comment: I think you can do that with the `shinyFiles` package.